# Datatable show/hide sorting/paging

Tags: .net, sorting, datatable, datatables, paging

I have a problem with datatables.net I want to show sorting/paging based on when the screnn width is over 700px and hide it when its under 700px. It works when i go from over 700px to under 700px but when i increase the width again the sorting/paging isnt showing again. I have read about datatables with destroy/retrieve attributes but i cant figure out whats wrong.

**This is fixed now with updated code below!**

My javascript code is looking like this:

```
   $(window).resize(function() {
    var isLarge = $(this).width() > 700;
    $('#transactionsTable').dataTable({
        destroy: true,
        searching: isLarge,
        paging: isLarge
    });
});
```

**My problem right now:**

For some reason when i change the screen width to check the responsive design the css doesn's seem to load correctly. So if i go from a big screen width to a smaller one the css for the top paging/searching doesn's load.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [description](https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve) of the `retrieve` option (emphasis mine):

> Retrieve the DataTables object for the given selector. Note that **if
>   the table has already been initialised, this parameter will cause
>   DataTables to simply return the object that has already been set up** -
>   it will not take account of any changes you might have made to the
>   initialisation object passed to DataTables (setting this parameter to
>   true is an acknowledgement that you understand this!).

You need to remove `retrieve: true` (and change to `destroy: true`) in your if case or just simplify it to

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var isLarge = $(this).width() > 700;
    $('#transactionsTable').dataTable({
        destroy: true,
        searching: isLarge,
        paging: isLarge
    });
});
```

Comment: I noticed when shifting between screen widths the bootstrap css doesn't reload back when going back to bigger screen width! Any suggestions? So when changing size the bootstrap css doesn't load at all

Comment: @AndreasJangefalk That sound more like a problem with bootstrap than with datatables (and I am not that familiar with bootstrap). Maybe ask a new question about that.

Comment: I managed to solve the problemm it was a few css classes that didnt load correctly. So when i added them in everything worked!